Can't set null for bool dart flutter
Currently I using Bloc Flutter to make a simple comment and reply but the issue show off when I do a function interaction (only like and dislike). I can't set null for bool. In this case the field isLike is store the value to demonstrate the interact of use whenever they like or not. The APIs are worked but when the case comment.isLike == true. I want to set the value of isLike is null but it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this issue, I take a lot of time to figure out but not found the solution yet.
This is the model


import 'package:move_app/data/models/user_model.dart';

class CommentModel {
  final int? id;
  final DateTime? updatedAt;
  final DateTime? createdAt;
  final DateTime? deletedAt;
  final String? content;
  final int? numberOfLike;
  final UserModel? user;
  final String? timeConvert;
  final int? videoId;
  final bool? isLike;
  final int? totalDonation;

  CommentModel({
    this.id,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.createdAt,
    this.deletedAt,
    this.content,
    this.numberOfLike,
    this.user,
    this.timeConvert,
    this.videoId,
    this.isLike,
    this.totalDonation
  });

  factory CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CommentModel(
      id: json['id'] as int?,
      updatedAt:
      json['updatedAt'] != null ? DateTime.parse(json['updatedAt']) : null,
      createdAt:
      json['createdAt'] != null ? DateTime.parse(json['createdAt']) : null,
      deletedAt:
      json['deletedAt'] != null ? DateTime.parse(json['deletedAt']) : null,
      content: json['content'] is String ? json['content'] : '',
      numberOfLike: json['numberOfLike'] as int?,
      user: json['user'] != null ? UserModel.fromJson(json['user']) : null,
      isLike: json['isLike'] as bool?,
      totalDonation: json['totalDonation'] as int?,
    );
  }

  CommentModel copyWith({
    int? id,
    DateTime? updatedAt,
    DateTime? createdAt,
    DateTime? deletedAt,
    String? content,
    int? numberOfLike,
    UserModel? user,
    String? timeConvert,
    bool? isLike,
    int? totalDonation
  }) {
    return CommentModel(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
        deletedAt: deletedAt ?? this.deletedAt,
        content: content ?? this.content,
        numberOfLike: numberOfLike ?? this.numberOfLike,
        user: user ?? this.user,
        timeConvert: timeConvert ?? this.timeConvert,
        isLike: isLike ?? this.isLike,
        totalDonation: totalDonation ?? this.totalDonation
    );
  }

}



here are the code for Bloc file


  void onVideoDetailLikeComment(
      VideoDetailLikeComment event,
      Emitter<VideoDetailState> emit,
      ) async {
    final comment = event.comment;

    var result;

    if (comment.isLike == null) {
      // If not liked yet
      final updatedComment = comment.copyWith(isLike: true);
      result = await commentRepository.postCommentReaction(updatedComment);
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          listComments: updateCommentList(state.listComments, updatedComment),
        ),
      );
    } else if (comment.isLike == true) {
      result = await commentRepository.deleteCommentReaction(comment.id!);
      if (result.isRight()) {
        // Set isLike to null for unliking
        final updatedComment = comment.copyWith(isLike: null);
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            listComments: updateCommentList(state.listComments, updatedComment),
          ),
        );
      }
    } else if (comment.isLike == false) {
      final updatedComment = comment.copyWith(isLike: true);
      result = await commentRepository.patchCommentReaction(updatedComment);
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          listComments: updateCommentList(state.listComments, updatedComment),
        ),
      );
    }

    result.fold(
          (error) {
        print("Error Like : ========== : $error");
      },
          (response) {
        print("Success Like : ========== : $response");
      },
    );
  }



This is the code for Event


import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import '../../../../data/models/comment_model.dart';

sealed class VideoDetailEvent extends Equatable {
  const VideoDetailEvent();
}

final class VideoDetailInitialEvent extends VideoDetailEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

final class VideoDetailSelectQualityEvent extends VideoDetailEvent {
  final String selectedQuality;

  const VideoDetailSelectQualityEvent(this.selectedQuality);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

final class VideoDetailCommentChangedEvent extends VideoDetailEvent {
  final String? comment;

  const VideoDetailCommentChangedEvent({
    this.comment,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [comment];
}
final class VideoDetailLikeComment extends VideoDetailEvent {
  final CommentModel? comment;

  const VideoDetailLikeComment({ this.comment});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [comment];
}



And this is State


import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import '../../../../data/models/comment_model.dart';

enum VideoDetailStatus {
  initial,
  processing,
  success,
  failure,
}

final class VideoDetailState extends Equatable {
  final VideoDetailStatus? status;
  final String? selectedQuality;
  final Map<String, String>? videoUrls;
  final String? inputComment;
  final List<CommentModel>? listComments;
  final Map<int, List<CommentModel>>? replies;
  final List<CommentModel>? listReplies;
  final int? lastCommentId;
  final CommentModel? commentModel;

  const VideoDetailState({
    this.videoUrls,
    this.status,
    this.selectedQuality,
    this.inputComment,
    this.listComments,
    this.replies,
    this.listReplies,
    this.lastCommentId,
    this.commentModel,
  });

  static VideoDetailState initial() => const VideoDetailState(
        status: VideoDetailStatus.initial,
      );

  VideoDetailState copyWith({
    VideoDetailStatus? status,
    String? selectedQuality,
    Map<String, String>? videoUrls,
    String? inputComment,
    List<CommentModel>? listComments,
    Map<int, List<CommentModel>>? replies,
    List<CommentModel>? listReplies,
    int? lastCommentId,
    CommentModel? commentModel,
  }) {
    return VideoDetailState(
        selectedQuality: selectedQuality ?? this.selectedQuality,
        status: status ?? this.status,
        videoUrls: videoUrls ?? this.videoUrls,
        inputComment: inputComment ?? this.inputComment,
        listComments: listComments ?? this.listComments,
        replies: replies ?? this.replies,
        listReplies: listReplies ?? this.listReplies,
        lastCommentId: lastCommentId ?? this.lastCommentId,
        commentModel: commentModel ?? this.commentModel);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        status,
        selectedQuality,
        inputComment,
        listComments,
        replies,
        listReplies,
        lastCommentId,
        commentModel
      ];
}




The problem is this:
isLike: isLike ?? this.isLike,

This basically means:

if parameter isLike is null, use the original value

In your case, you’re setting isLike to null, so it defaults to this.isLike, which is true.
You’ll have to change your copyWith logic

Thanks for your solution and I really appreciate it. But the field isLike not always null it have to follow the value from APIs, if we set that the value of isLike always default null from the beginning. I have found the other solution that I created an enum LikeStatus instead of use isLike, when I get the value from APIs I set the value for it matching with value of isLike(true, false or null when isLike not exist) and now the role of isLike here is just to assign value to LikeStatus when data change. Anyway, thank for your solution ❤️
